# Code Templates does not work in NetBeans 11

Tags: shortcut, code-templates, netbeans-11

I just updated from  Netbeans 8.2 to 11 and it seems like Code Templates has stopped working.  For example, **sout + tab** should give  a `System.out.println(...)` and **psvm + tab** should give a `public static void main (..){}`

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if, is there a fix?

It's really annoying since, once you get used to the Code Template Shortcuts, they are hard to live without.

Right now I had to go back to 8.2

Comment: It worked for me out of the box. Have you had a look under "Tools / Options / Editor / Code Templates" if the code templates are present and "Expand template on" is set to "tab"?

Comment: I already checked that (compared to my 8.2 options) and that's not the problem. Actually, I think theres a problem with my installation, since I found other things that do not work. For example, the wizard "create new Package" creates a file, not a package, and many other "strange things".

How did you install NetBeans 11? I am running Windows 8.2, and downloaded the zip-file, and are running netbeans64 directly from the bin-folder

Comment: I also just downloaded, unzipped and started NetBeans. Maybe you could try to delete the NetBeans cache (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.0) and also the user directory (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0)

Comment: Deleting the Cache and User Directory solved the problem (and all the others). Thanks, Joachim.
Can you put your suggestion as an answer, so I can close the question, and provide others with the same problem with a quick way to find the fix?

Comment: This problem seemed to occur for me after installing something I was prompted to install/update after launching a fresh install of Netbeans 11.0 (perhaps nbjavac). I can't be sure which but it was definitely working when I first installed Netbeans 11.0 before running those updates. If need be, test on a fresh install without updating anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the NetBeans cache (`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.0`) and also the user directory (`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.0`).

Comment: This solution also worked for me on Ubuntu where the cache directory is found at `~/.cache/netbeans/11.0`

Comment: is this method affecting current netbean preferences? because the folder contain so many datafile its even reaching 5 GB

Comment: Deleting the cache is not affecting your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing 1 of your code templates (extra Enter) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it helped to just rename the file of the Language where i had the issue. For me it was x-php5:
`(C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\20\config\Editors\text\x-php5\CodeTemplates\)`.

so I had a backup of the already configured code template and still kept the other user settings.
I did this while netbeans was open. I then just created a new dummy setting - and everything worked again.

Hope this helps somebody - as it was very annoying for me...